# Why does this PDO connection fail?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'uname';
$password = 'password';
$dbName = 'events';
if (class_exists('PDO')){
    echo("PDO Exists");
} 
else {
    echo("PDO Does Not Exist");
}
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    die($error);
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM event');
$stmt->execute();
$events = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($events);
```

Output is

```
PDO Exists
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/blah/getEvents.php on line 25
```

Comment: What die var_dump of $pdo give you right after you attempt to instantiate?

Comment: var_dump($pdo) spits object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: That is really bizarre. So you have a valid PDO object yet a few lines later it seems you can't call `prepare()` on it.

Comment: Very strange, I moved this code to a friends server and it runs as expected. I though it must be something up with the version of php on my server so I thought I'd give it one last go and now it seems to work. The only changes I'm aware of making was deleting some white space and changing the single quotes in the prepare to double quotes. Spooky.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `$pdo` object is not defined in that scope. Move

`$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM event');` to the try statement after the `$pdo` variable is declared and instantiated.

in order to execute that query you need to call the execute method:

`$stmt->execute();`

To debug this you need to do a `var_dump($pdo)` to see what it contains.

Comment: I bet this answer is on the right track, though. The OP probably is running the prepare in a function that they haven't shown. And PHP *does* have function level scoping, so the function would have to declare `global $pdo` or else pass it into the function as an argument.

Comment: This is not in a function. I've updated the post to show everything between the php brackets. It's a very simple file, I've no idea why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is probably not being thrown. Enable exceptions like so:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

Comment: That is my initial thought as well, though the documentation would suggest that PDOException would ALWAYS be thrown by constructor regardless of `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` setting. See note midway down on this page: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php  It's a bit of a head scratcher to me as to how the PDO object wouldn't be set without the PDOException being thrown by constructor. I would be tempted to remove the try-catch block to see what happens.

Comment: Good point, documentation does indeed state this. My guess is we are not quite seeing all of the code then.